# ASP.NET CORE: Ошибка: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Не могу понять, почему не устанавливается ссылка на обьект с использованием Entity Framework Core.

Мои модели:

```
public class Album
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Genre")]
    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Artist")]
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Album Art URL")]
    [StringLength(1024)]
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

Контекст:

```
public class MusicStoreEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artist { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

    public MusicStoreEntities(DbContextOptions<MusicStoreEntities> options): base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Код заполнения первоначальными данными:

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void Initialize(MusicStoreEntities entities)
    {
        entities.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (entities.Genres.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }
        
        var genres = new Genre[]
        {
            new Genre { Name = "Rock" },
            new Genre { Name = "Jazz" },
            new Genre { Name = "Metal" },
            new Genre { Name = "Alternative" },
            new Genre { Name = "Disco" },
            new Genre { Name = "Blues" },
            new Genre { Name = "Latin" },
            new Genre { Name = "Reggae" },
            new Genre { Name = "Pop" },
            new Genre { Name = "Classical" }
        };

        foreach (Genre g in genres)
        {
            entities.Genres.Add(g);
        }
        entities.SaveChanges();

        var artists = new Artist[]
        {
          new Artist { Name = "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra" },
            new Artist { Name = "Aaron Goldberg" },
            new Artist { Name = "AC/DC" },
            new Artist { Name = "Accept" },
            new Artist { Name = "Adrian Leaper & Doreen de Feis" },
            new Artist { Name = "Aerosmith" },
            new Artist { Name = "Aisha Duo" },
  
        };           

        var albums = new Album[]
        {
              new Album { Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Classical"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"), AlbumArtUrl = $""},
            new Album { Title = "Worlds", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Jazz"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Goldberg"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
            new Album { Title = "For Those About To Rock We Salute You", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Rock"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "AC/DC"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
            new Album { Title = "Let There Be Rock", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Rock"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "AC/DC"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
          
        };

        foreach (Album a in albums)
        {
            entities.Albums.Add(a);
        }
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Ошибка здесь, в методе Details, при откладке переменная album не имеет ссылки на Genre, Artist. В представлении это строка: `@Model.Genre.Name` выдает ошибку:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Другие методы работают. БД полностью заполнена.

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    MusicStoreEntities storeDb;
    public StoreController(MusicStoreEntities storeDb)
    {
        this.storeDb = storeDb;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var genres = storeDb.Genres.ToList();
        return View(genres);
    }

    // GET: /Store/Browse
    public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
    {
        var genreModel = storeDb.Genres.Include("Albums")
        .Single(g => g.Name == genre);

        return View(genreModel);
    }
    // GET: /Store/Details
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var album = storeDb.Albums.Find(id);
        return View(album);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы используете технологии `Core`, то не ставьте лишние метки, не относящиеся к этой технологии.

Comment: Если вылетает это исключение, значит метод `Find` не нашёл сущность. Это значит, что в БД нет записи с таким `id`. | В любом случае в коде должна быть проверка наподобие: `if (album == null) ...`

Comment: В БД данные есть, ошибка в том, что класс Album не имеет ссылку на класс Genre. Этот проект делался на ASP.NET MVC, и там все работало, я его на Core хочу перенести.

Comment: Стало немного понятнее. Тогда такой вопрос: раньше использовался Entity Framework? Без Core?

Comment: да, вот ссылка на проект на ASP.NET MVC, который я делаю для Core: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8

Comment: Модификатор `virtual` на свойствах моделей EF используется для указания ленивой загрузки (lazy loading). В EF Core загрузка связанных данных осуществляется по-другому. [Loading Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Comment: `storeDb.Entry(album).Reference(a => a.Genre).Load();` - добавить после метода `Find`.

Comment: Сработало) Не знал, что так можно было. Спасибо!